# How to clone the Mesh of a Line object in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, line

Im trying to create a for loop of 10 lines . However line.Clone() gives me an error, since it doesnt find any mesh to clone from? Please if you know how to acces the mesh of a line let me know.

Here is some code:

```
forward_RT(){

    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff ); //White Color
    spotLight.position.set( 150, 500, -210 );
    scene_Main.add( spotLight );

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( spotLight.position.x, spotLight.position.y, spotLight.position.z) );
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( ray_End_pos_X, ray_End_pos_Y, ray_End_pos_Z) );

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
        //Also tried 
        //var newLine = line.clone(); & scene_Main.add(newLine);
        scene.add(line.clone());

        ray_End_pos_X += 50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code (e.g. you increment ray_End_pos_X but do not use it in the loop). I have a suspicion you probably only need to change geometry during each iteration.

I would go with new lines from cloned geometry and shared material. I quickly checked, this works:

```
    var rayX = 0, rayY=0, rayZ = 0;

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( spotLight.position.x, spotLight.position.y, spotLight.position.z) );
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( rayX, rayY, rayZ) );

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        var newLine = new THREE.Line(geometry.clone(), material);
        newLine.geometry.vertices[1].x = rayX;
        this.context.scene.add(newLine);
        rayX += 0.1;
    }
```

This is how it looks (red lines, the rest is irrelevant):

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou to be honest, `line.clone()` is failing for me too. I suspect it needs some pre-calculations before you can clone it. If I have time, I will update the answer. Since `line.clone()` calls line constructor and does copy(), you do not loose any efficiency with the approach above. But I am still curious why clone() does not work.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that too. And I think the developers of Three.js came up with this extensional library [MeshLine.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three.meshline). I'm still new to this technology, and I don't know if it's relevant in this case, but have a look on that link.